# Edit the Time in a JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, time, calendar, jtable

Right now, I have a Calendar and using `SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm")` I convert the Calendar time to a string and put it in a JTable Cell. The cell is editable, but how do I check if the the edited value is properly formed as `hh:mm` and if it's not change it back to the old time?

Or is their another way to put the time in a cell and being able to edit it?

Comment: Sounds like you need an editor which uses validation, e.g. a `JFormattedTextField`

Comment: @Robin: Defenitely going to try that out, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write your own custom data model, rendered and cell editor.
Take a look at setModel(), setDefaultRenderer() and setDefaultEditor().
Here is a great tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

I wrote simple example for you:

```
package test;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JTable;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class Poligon extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Poligon frame = new Poligon();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public Poligon() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DataModel("12:34:00"));
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Date.class, new DateRenderer());
        table.setDefaultEditor(Date.class, new DateEditor());
        table.setRowHeight(35);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);


    }

}

class DateRenderer implements TableCellRenderer
{

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        JPanel c = new JPanel();

        if (value instanceof Date)
        {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            c.add(new JLabel(dateFormat.format(value)));
        }

        return c;
    }

}

class DateEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor
{

    private Object cellEditorValue;

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {    
        return this.cellEditorValue;
    }

    public void setCellEditorValue(Object value)
    {
        this.cellEditorValue = value;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table,  Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int col) 
    {   

        JPanel c = new JPanel();

        if (value instanceof Date)
        {
            final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");

            final JTextField textField = new JTextField();

            textField.setText(dateFormat.format(value));

            textField.addCaretListener(new CaretListenerForDate(this, textField));

            c.add(textField);       
        }

        return c;
    }

}

class CaretListenerForDate implements CaretListener
{       
    private JTextField textField;
    private DateEditor dateEditor;

    public CaretListenerForDate(DateEditor dateEditor, JTextField textField)
    {
        this.textField = textField;
        this.dateEditor = dateEditor;
    }

    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); 
        try {
            dateEditor.setCellEditorValue(dateFormat.parse(textField.getText()));
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            System.err.println(String.format("Worng date format! [%s] Error is [%s]", textField.getText(), e1.getMessage() ));
        }

    }                               
}

class DataModel extends AbstractTableModel
{

    private String timeString;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); 

    public DataModel(String time) {
        this.timeString = time;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        if (col >= 0) {
            return Date.class;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) 
    {
        return col >= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {

        Date date = null;

        try {
            date = dateFormat.parse(timeString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {           

        this.timeString = dateFormat.format(aValue);

        this.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the example, useful and defenitely learned a lot from it!

Comment: A `TableCellRenderer` which creates a new component (in this case a `JPanel` and a `JLabel`) is a real performance killer. You should adjust an existing component in your renderer.

Comment: Robin, you are right. This should never be used in the real code.

Comment: if you know what you shouldn't use in real code ... don't show it in examples (errors tend to be sticky ;-) Other problems, f.i.: a) the editor implementation is invalid (it _must_ notify listeners when terminating for internal reasons) b) getColumnClass must not return null c) if you have a Date as data, store the date (vs. converting back/forth in the getter/setter) d) no need for a parent panel, neither in the editor nor the renderer e) the text component intended for use with formatted text is ... JFormattedText :-) Hope that @P1nGu1n doesn't take over any of those

Answer (score 0):

You can check it using simple regular expression like this one:

```
(([01]\d)|(2[0-3])):([0-5]\d)
```

Comment: But how do I return to the old value, if the submitted one isn't valid?

Comment: @P1nGu1n Save its old value in separate field and place it back when input is not valid.